# Firebase update a value if sibling value equals something

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a list of books i need to add cover images to. When i print out the list of books i append an Id using the Book Id from my Firebase Database, i then have an input field to grab the user added cover image url which i want to update the Firebase database with.

I want to find the child where the Id matches the book i want to add a cover to and then add or update the cover value in Firebase with the new url

Overview of Firebase

```
Books
 0
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5


Books
 0
 1
  Author: "Susanna Clarke"
  Average Rating: 4.3
  Book Id: 48496334
  Cover: "../img/bookCovers/piranesi.jpg"
 2
 3
 4
 5
```

Firebase Rules

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "Books": {
      ".indexOn": ["Book Id"]
    }
  }
}
```

JS

```
let bookID = pickedFromPrintedOutBook;
let bookCoverURL = pickedFromTextInputValue;

// This works fine and gets the correct Book I want
const book = firebase.database().ref('/testing1234/').orderByChild('Book Id').equalTo(bookID);
 book.on('value', function(snapshot) {
 console.log(snapshot.val());
});

firebase.database().ref('/Books/').orderByChild("Book Id").equalTo(bookID).once("child_added", function(snapshot){
 snapshot.val().update({
  "Cover": bookCoverURL
 });
})
```

If i console.log as i go i can see the correct book being picked, the new cover image url being grabbed etc but in my Chrome console i simply get

```
TypeError: snapshot.val(...).update is not a function
Uncaught TypeError: snapshot.val(...).update is not a function
```

And Firebase doesnt update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `.update()` on the value. That's going to be an object. The update method can be used on a [Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.Reference). You can get the DB Reference from the snapshot like this:

```
firebase.database().ref('/Books/').orderByChild("BookId").equalTo(bookID).once("child_added", function(snapshot){
 snapshot.ref.update({
  "Cover": bookCoverURL
 });
})
```